# i want to change the value of the variable 'inner' from outside the closure but my ouput appears to be undefined

Tags: javascript, closures

I have written this code of trying to change the value of the variable 'inner' from outside the closure. the output is undefined, I wonder why.

```js
function welcome(name) {
  var inner = "  to   "

  function innerF(location) {
    let hi = "helo"
    let text = hi + " " + name + " " + "welcome" + inner + location
    return text
  }

  function sayHi() {
    return 'abc'
  }

  function setName(newName) {
    inner = newName;
  }
  return {
    first: innerF,
    second: sayHi,
    third: setName
  }

}
var result = welcome('arpit')
console.log('>>', result.first('ktm'))
console.log('>>', result.third('hari'))
```

I want the value of 'inner' to be 'hari'

Answer (score 1):

You didn't return the value in `setName()` function.

```js
function welcome(name) {
  var inner = "  to   "

  function innerF(location) {
    let hi = "helo"
    let text = hi + " " + name + " " + "welcome" + inner + location
    return text
  }

  function sayHi() {
    return 'abc'
  }

  function setName(newName) {
    return inner = newName;
  }
  return {
    first: innerF,
    second: sayHi,
    third: setName
  }

}
var result = welcome('arpit')
console.log('>>', result.first('ktm'))
console.log('>>', result.third('hari'))
```